# Is there support provided for DataTable in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, datatable, xamarin.forms

I have to use DataTable in Xamarin.Forms. I don't know whether there is support provided for DataTable in Xamarin.Forms. So please someone clear this.

Comment: What kind of support? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Where are you getting this datatable from?

Comment: I am creating DataTable manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTable binding is not supported.

You will be better of creating a method that will convert your datatable to List of the corresponding type. Then use that list or its observable collection to Bind.

In mobiles data is usually retrieved as JSON, hence there is not much use of Data table as in other places.

Look into [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Observable collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) and use them for [Data Binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) in Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Hi Rohit, thank you for the response. It is very useful for me. Could you please tell me why DataTable is not supported in Xamarin.Forms. Any specific point?

Comment: @Divakar : I can say that Xamarin Forms team don't want to integrate it. There might be difficulties, but too obvious reason is , it's not supported natively by platforms.
I disagree with Rohit's answer that there is not much use of it. We can do multiple things easily with Data Tables like sorting data based on columns.